# Azure APIM and cloud service SSL not working

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-api-management

I have a cloud service and an Azure APIM instance with a self signed client cert setup on them (the cert has intended purposes of server auth and client auth).

Each API within the APIM has the client cert setup on its security. However, when I perform the call the following comes back in the trace.

"messages":["Error occured while calling backend service.","The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.","The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Is there anything I am missing here, searching online and cannot see anything obvious.

Comment: So it seems I need to allow self signed certificates within APIM. Just trying to find out how (seems it needs doing via the API Management REST API)

Comment: Check this out [Self-Signed Certificate in APIM for Mutual authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-backend-entity)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct, the option is not available in the portal to allow self-signed certificates. Here is a blogpost by **Sasha Rosenbaum**: http://divineops.net/enable-self-signed-certificates-in-azure-api-management-services/

Here basically you are skipping the certificate verification using "**[skipCertificateChainValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-backend-entity)**" attribute.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I found this blog post a while ago. I realised the mistake i made when running it through. The host needed to be the host name of the end point api

Comment: Yea thats another thing to keep a tab on. I just added the image as a reference from the blogpost.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a backend entity through power shell scripts to skipcertifioc